# Postfix smtp mail server and client

Tags: email, ubuntu, smtp, postfix-mta

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS SMTP server running postfix and the postfix is currently sending email correctly.

I am looking for suggestions on how to allow the automated system that sends email through the server to send an email to an address on the server.  When the email gets there I want to be able to search the subject line for a value and then forward the message to the correct external email address from there.

My first thought was to load an email client that allows the establishment of rules and set a rule to look for the value in the subject line and then forward the email and then delete the email.

This is a Ubuntu server that does not have a gui installed to I am looking for the solution that would require the least amount of package installation as this is all the server will be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want postfix itself to handle forwarding of mails, based on the `Subject` header, you can do it with `header_checks`. Add the following to your `main.cf`

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
#...
#...
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks.re
#...
#...
#/etc/postfix/header_checks.re
/^Subject:(.*)Accounts/       REDIRECT  accounts@example.org   
/^Subject:(.*)HR/       REDIRECT    hr@example.org
```

If all the emails sent through postfix, get delivered to some mailbox and you want the `IMAP Server` (For eg. `Dovecot`), handling those mailboxes, to do this redirection stuff, you can use `sieve` rules to do it. Also i don't recommend doing it email clients.

Hope that helps.